# Reverse List without duplicates ( convert it into Set ) -> Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, set

I need to delete all duplicates from a list and then show it in reverse order.

So far I have this:

```
reverseInSet([], Y,R):-
 R=Y.

reverseInSet([H|T], Y, R):- 
 removeElement(H,T,T1), 
 reverseInSet(T1, [H|Y], R).


removeElement(_,[],[]).    

removeElement(X,[X|T],L):-    
 removeElement(X,T,L).

removeElement(X,[Y|T],L):-   
 removeElement(X,T,L1),
 L=[Y|L1].
```

And the output is this:

```
reverseInSet([1,2,3,3,9,3],[],P).
P = [9, 3, 2, 1]
P = [3, 9, 3, 2, 1]
P = [9, 3, 3, 2, 1]
P = [9, 3, 3, 2, 1]
P = [3, 9, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using [reif library](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=reif), to be both pure and reasonably deterministic:

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).

reverse_without_duplicates(Lst, LstRevDeDup) :-
    reverse_without_duplicates_(Lst, [], LstRevDeDup).


reverse_without_duplicates_([], Lst, Lst).

reverse_without_duplicates_([H|T], Upto, LstRevDeDup) :-
    memberd_t(H, T, Bool),
    reverse_without_duplicates_bool_(Bool, T, H, Upto, LstRevDeDup).

reverse_without_duplicates_bool_(true, T, _H, Upto, LstRevDeDup) :-
    reverse_without_duplicates_(T, Upto, LstRevDeDup).
reverse_without_duplicates_bool_(false, T, H, Upto, LstRevDeDup) :-
    % Include head
    reverse_without_duplicates_(T, [H|Upto], LstRevDeDup).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(reverse_without_duplicates([1, 2, 3, 3, 9, 3], X)).
% 52 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (88% CPU, 1025277 Lips)
X = [3,9,2,1].
```

This pure method shows sensible answers with:

```
?- time(reverse_without_duplicates([1, 2, N, 3, 9, 3], L)).
% 49 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (87% CPU, 1030603 Lips)
N = 1,
L = [3,9,1,2] ;
% 127 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (98% CPU, 845646 Lips)
N = 2,
L = [3,9,2,1] ;
% 152 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (98% CPU, 1051910 Lips)
N = 3,
L = [3,9,2,1] ;
% 178 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (98% CPU, 1229859 Lips)
N = 9,
L = [3,9,2,1] ;
% 88 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (97% CPU, 648633 Lips)
L = [3,9,N,2,1],
dif(N,1),
dif(N,9),
dif(N,3),
dif(N,2).
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about the simplest way to do it. In the case of duplicate entries in the source list, the last such entry is kept and the ones preceding it are discarded.

```
list_to_set_reverse( Xs, Ys ) :- list_to_set( Xs, Zs ) , reverse(Zs,Ys) .

list_to_set( []     , []     ) .
list_to_set( [X|Xs] , Ys     ) :- member(X,Xs), !, list_to_set(Xs,Ys) .
list_to_set( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :-                  list_to_set(Xs,Ys) .
```

You could  also do it in a single pass, too. You just need to use an accumulator to build the result list in reverse order:

```
list_to_set_reverse( Xs, Ys ) :- list_to_set( Xs, [], Ys ) .

list_to_set( []     , Ys , Ys ) .
list_to_set( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :- member(X,Xs), !, list_to_set(Xs,Ts,Ys) .
list_to_set( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :-                  list_to_set(Xs,[X|Ts],Ys) .
```

This also keeps the last duplicates in the source list. But, since we're using an accumulator here to build the result list, it's easy enough to rejigger it to keep the first of any duplicate items: we just check to see if a candidate item is already in the result set or not (rather than check to see if it occurs later in the source list).

```
list_to_set_reverse( Xs, Ys ) :- list_to_set( Xs, [], Ys ) .

list_to_set( []     , Ys , Ys ) .
list_to_set( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :- member(X,Ts), !, list_to_set(Xs,Ts,Ys).
list_to_set( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :-                  list_to_set(Xs,[X|Ts],Ys) .
```