# Delete from a list the non-duplicated items

Tags: list, prolog, logical-purity

I need to do an exercise where I must eliminate the elements of a list that are NOT duplicated, previously I made one to eliminate the elements of a list that ARE duplicated. This is my code to eliminate the elements that ARE duplicated in a list but I don't know how to modify it to generate a new code to eliminate the elements of a list that are NOT duplicated. Can somebody help me? Please.

```
simp([H,H|T],X):-!, simp([H|T],X).
simp([H|T],[H|X]):-simp(T,X).
```

Comment: 1. Your `simp` predicate doesn't work well. For example, `?- simp([1,2,3,1,4,2,5], X).` returns `false`. 2. I just want to clarify your idea. What do you mean by "eliminate the elements that ARE duplicated"? For example, `?- simp([1,2,3,1,4,2,5], X).`, you want to get `X=[3,4,5]` or `X=[1,2,3,4,5]` or `X=[3,1,4,2,5]`?

Comment: Of course, you want "eliminate the elements of a list that are NOT duplicated". My comment above focused on your solution of "eliminate the elements that ARE duplicated in a list". Just to clarify your point.

Comment: @chansey Hello, for example. If I write ```?- eliminate([a,b,1,2,c,a,2,1,4], R). ```. I wan to get ```R = [a,1,2]. ``` Other example is ```eliminate([1,2,3,4], R). R = [].``` Because there isn’t an element duplicated and returns the empty list.

Answer (score 2):

Using reif library, to be both pure and reasonably deterministic ([similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71298345/reverse-list-without-duplicates-convert-it-into-set-prolog)):

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).

duplicate_elements(LstFull, LstDuplicates) :-
    duplicate_elements_(LstFull, [], LstDuplicatesRev),
    reverse(LstDuplicatesRev, LstDuplicates).

duplicate_elements_([], L, L).
% U means LstUpto
duplicate_elements_([H|T], U, LstD) :-
    memberd_t(H, T, Bool),
    (Bool == true -> duplicate_elements_add_(U, H, U1) ; U1 = U),
    duplicate_elements_(T, U1, LstD).

duplicate_elements_add_(U, E, U1) :-
    % Prevent adding a duplicate to U1 more than once
    (memberchk(E, U) -> U1 = U ; U1 = [E|U]).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(duplicate_elements([a,b,1,2,c,A,2,1,4], D)).
% 105 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (92% CPU, 1494726 Lips)
A = a,
D = [a,1,2] ;
% 177 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (94% CPU, 1261726 Lips)
A = b,
D = [b,1,2] ;
% 193 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (98% CPU, 1288643 Lips)
A = 1,
D = [1,2] ;
% 214 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (96% CPU, 1349996 Lips)
A = 2,
D = [1,2] ;
% 237 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (98% CPU, 1515152 Lips)
A = c,
D = [1,2,c] ;
% 360 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (99% CPU, 1892217 Lips)
A = 4,
D = [1,2,4] ;
% 49 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (95% CPU, 575563 Lips)
D = [1,2],
dif(A,a),
dif(A,4),
dif(A,c),
dif(A,2),
dif(A,1),
dif(A,b).
```

Comment: `remove_unique_elems([a,a],[a,a])` fails. And `a` is not unique here, so you cannot remove it.

Comment: Stylistic remark: why no `if_/3`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your question is ambiguous, you said that

> eliminate the elements of a list that are NOT duplicated

It should mean to remove the unique elements.

For example,

```
?- remove_unique_elems([a,b,1,2,c,a,2,1,4], R). 
R = [a,1,2,a,2,1].
```

However, in the comment later, you also said that

> If I write `?- eliminate([a,b,1,2,c,a,2,1,4], R).` . I wan to get `R = [a,1,2].`

That is not "remove the unique elements", but "get the duplicate elements as a 'set', but keep the original order".

Nevertheless, I will still give you two solutions:

1. Define `dup` to generate all duplicate elements

   ```
   delete(X,[X|L],L) :- !.
   delete(Y,[X|Xs],[X|Xt]) :- delete(Y,Xs,Xt).

   dup(X,L) :- member(X,L), delete(X,L,L2), memberchk(X,L2).

   ?- dup(X,[a,b,1,2,c,a,2,1,4]).
   X = a ;
   X = 1 ;
   X = 2 ;
   X = a ;
   X = 2 ;
   X = 1 ;
   false.;

   ?- dup(X,[1,2,3,4]).
   false.
   ```
2. Define `remove_unique_elems`

   ```
   remove_unique_elems(L,R) :-
     (   bagof(X, dup(X,L), Xs)
     ->  R = Xs
     ;   R = []
     ).

   ?- remove_unique_elems([a,b,1,2,c,a,2,1,4], R).
   R = [a,1,2,a,2,1].

   ?- remove_unique_elems([1,2,3,4], R).
   R = [].

   ?- remove_unique_elems([a,a],[a,a]).
   true.
   ```
3. Define `duplicate_elements`

   ```
   remove_dup(DL,NDL) :- reverse(DL, DLR), remove_dup_(DLR, NDLR),reverse(NDLR, NDL).
   remove_dup_([], []) :- !.
   remove_dup_([X|Xs], L) :- member(X, Xs), !, remove_dup_(Xs, L).
   remove_dup_([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- remove_dup_(Xs, Ys).

   duplicate_elements(L,R) :-
     (   bagof(X, dup(X,L), Xs)
     ->  remove_dup(Xs, R)
     ;   R = []
     ).

   ?- duplicate_elements([a,b,1,2,c,a,2,1,4], R).
   R = [a,1,2].

   ?- duplicate_elements([1,2,3,4], R).
   R = [].

   ?- duplicate_elements([a,a], [a,a]).
   false.
   ```